# Deserializar JSON de MongoDB en Android

Tags: java, android, mongodb

Soy relativamente nuevo en el desarrollo movil estaba trabajando con Mongo consumiendo un API que local pero ahora quiero saber como poder deserializar los datos del JSON que consumo del API.
[image: JSON de MONOGDB]

Aquí esta el como lo estoy trabajando (Localhost), he logrado que me lo muestre como un String pero me gustaria serializarlo para trabajarlo mejor.

Si alguien pudiese orientarme sobre el como hacerlo, de antemano gracias y un saludo!

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        //hacer solicitud GET
        new GetDataTask().execute("http://[IP]:3000/api/product/5c2ae8c084f3ef3ffc369157");
    }

    class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                return getData(params[0]);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "Network error !";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //configurar la respuesta de datos a textView
            mResult.setText("\n"+result);

            //cancelar el diálogo de progreso
            if (progressDialog != null) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        private String getData(String urlPath) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =null;

            try {
                //Inicializar y configurar la solicitud, luego conectarse al servidor
                URL url = new URL(urlPath);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Establecer encabezado
                urlConnection.connect();

                //Leer la respuesta de datos del servidor
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }


            } finally {
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }

            return result.toString();
        }

    }
```

Asi es como he logrado que me muestre el JSON:

[image: Muestra del JSON]

Por eso quiero aprender a deserializarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido lo que quieres mostrar es la imagen a que te refieres con deserializar?

Comment: Por el momento solo quisiera acomodar la información, con los campos que solo me gustaria mostrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido. Imagino que lo que te gustaria es tener un Array cargado con los datos que te vienen en el json.

Para ayudarnos a parsear lo mejor es convertir el string en un [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) y [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) segun corresponda y luego ir recorriendolos para extraer los datos.

Aca te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como podria ser:

```
private Array<Product> parseProducts(String result){
   Array<Product> products = new Array()
   //Primero instanciamos un objeto json con el String que ya conseguiste:
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

   //Leemos el campo products que contiene el Array de productos.
   JSONArray jProducts = json.getJSONArray("products")

   for (JSONObject jProduct : json){ //Recorro el array para parsear cada producto

      Product product = new Product();//Crea tu propio modelo Producto para que contenga los datos que vallas a necesitar

      try{
         product.id = jProduct.getString("_id");//Asi consigo finalmente los campos del json
         product.name = jProduct.getString("name");
         product.price = jProduct.getDouble("price");
         //Continuar con los demas campos...

      }catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      array.add(product)
   }
   return products;
}
```

Comment: El "Product" solo para aclarar es una clase que debo crear aparte con los atributos que quiero que muestre o es una variable que debo crear en mi MainActivity

Comment: Si, exacto. Es una clase que debes crear con atributos y todo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar este método y aplicarlo a tu estructura json:

Clase para almacenar la estructura de dato:

```
public class Event {

/** Titulo */
public final String titulo;

/** Numero de personas que sintio el terremoto */
public final String numeroPersonas;

/** sensasion */
public final String intensidad;


public Event(String titulo, String numeroPersonas, String intensidad) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.numeroPersonas = numeroPersonas;
    this.intensidad = intensidad;
}
}
```

aplicacion de la clase

```
private static Event extraccionCaracteristicasDelJson(String terremotosJSON) {
    // en caso de que este vacio el json
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(terremotosJSON)) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        JSONObject baseJson = new JSONObject(terremotosJSON);
        JSONArray caracteristicasArray = baseJson.getJSONArray("items");

        // si existe algun resultado
        if (caracteristicasArray.length() > 0) {
            // Se extrae el primer elemento de interes
            JSONObject elemento = caracteristicasArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject propiedades = elemento.getJSONObject("properties");

            // Extract out the title, number of people, and perceived strength values
            String titulo = propiedades.getString("title");
            String numeroPersonas = propiedades.getString("felt");
            String intensidad = propiedades.getString("cdi");

            // se llena y retorna una clase con la estructura de interés
            return new Event(titulo, numeroPersonas, intensidad);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema con el resultado json", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: el private static Event que es? lo estoy tratando de implementar en mi MainActivuty y no me da la opcion como tal de un static Event.